# BPMN how to model repetable tasks

Tags: modeling, jbpm, bpmn

I'm trying to model a task that can be executed more that one time.

Is the only way to do this the one on the figure below?

Is there in a BPMN task an attribute that is used to specify the *repeatability* of a task??

[image: bpmn loop]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a **loop marker** to indicate that a task is repeating.

[image: loop marker]

Alternatively you can mark your activity as being **multi-instance**. There's a sequential variant:

[image: sequential multi-instance]

And also a parallel variant:

[image: parallel multi-instance]

If you have a specific termination condition for your loop, i.e. something more specific than "Completed?", you might want to go with your original diagram to make the termination condition clear.
See [here](http://www.ny-central.org/process/bpmn-2-0/bpmn-2-0-loops/) for more info.

Comment: Be aware, most BPM engine implementations I am aware of do not support the looping option and require a specific count for the multi-instance implementation. If the termination condition is from an external system (or another process) then you can break out using a signal or message boundary event as well.